# Trouble Downloading Drupal on Linux Permission Denied

Tags: linux, drupal

When I try to download Drupal I get denied permission. How can I bypass this?

```
 /var/www$ wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz
```

This results in:

```
    --2012-02-08 21:20:17--  http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.drupal.org... 64.50.233.100, 64.50.236.52
Connecting to ftp.drupal.org|64.50.233.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2728271 (2.6M) [application/x-gzip]
drupal-7.0.tar.gz: Permission denied

Cannot write to `drupal-7.0.tar.gz' (Permission denied).
eyedea@eyedea-ER912AA-ABA-SR1810NX-NA620:/var/www$ ^C
eyedea@eyedea-ER912AA-ABA-SR1810NX-NA620:/var/www$ wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz
--2012-02-08 21:46:34--  http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.drupal.org... 64.50.236.52, 64.50.233.100
Connecting to ftp.drupal.org|64.50.236.52|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2728271 (2.6M) [application/x-gzip]
drupal-7.0.tar.gz: Permission denied

Cannot write to `drupal-7.0.tar.gz' (Permission denied).
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question; Probably better asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It looks like you are trying to download directly to the /var/www directory. Your normal user probably doesn't have permission to write to that location. You should download it to your home directory, unpack it, and the move it to the appropriate folder. In order to solve this you should read about the file system permissions. This link will explain most of it: [linux files and file permissions](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugfilesp.html). I assume you are using linux, but it should be very similar on other unix variants.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be, you don't have permission or your disk is full.
Try 
$ sudo wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz

If dowsn't work, then do
$ df -h

Your / filesystem should not be full